# VSCode - invoke nosetests for a specific function or class

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, nose

I've setup a task in `tasks.json` to run `nosetests` from within VSCode, but, I'd like to invoke specific tests, eg a function or class of tests.  Can anyone see a way to do this? In the tasks variable substitution I don't see function or class as variables.

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "/Users/alex/.virtualenvs/ddc/bin/nosetests",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-v"],
    "showOutput": "always",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "${file}",
            "isTestCommand": true,
            "args": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way that you can setup tests to run is to modify your settings.json file. In order to get the tests to be auto discovered so that you can run and debug you'll need to have settings that look like the following:

```js
{
    ...,
    "python.pythonPath": "venv\\Sciprts\\python.exe",
    "python.testing.nosetestArgs": [
        "--all-modules",
        "--traverse-namespace",
        "--ignore-files=venv",
        "."
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled": true
}
```

The important part of this is the nosetestArgs, these are what is passed into nosetests when doing test discovery. Now VSCode should pick up your tests and you should be able to run/debug them.

Answer (score 1):

@Alex, I'm the author of the extension, the solution is as follows:
(the plan is to make this a seamless experience in the future)

1. Create a file named xyz.py in the root directory
2. Add the following code
3. Add a break point in you test method (the test method you wish to debug)
4. Start debugging

`import nose 
nose.run()`

Comment: Cool.  To make sure I'm understanding it: that would run all the tests, but let you stop on the one I'm interested in?

In this scenario I don't want to debug the test, just run it.  The reason I only want to run one test is so that I'm not waiting for the other tests to complete while I work on this method.